# How to prevent Pandas Dataframe from repeating column names at every row?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am working with ExactTarget Saleforce marketing cloud SOAP API for work. I have gotten the API to respond to my application and the responses are a list of dictionaries. Like so:

```
ClickEvent){
   Client = 
      (ClientID){
         ID = 111111
      }
   PartnerKey = None
   CreatedDate = 2016-07-12 00:40:17
   ModifiedDate = 2016-07-12 00:40:17
   ID = 11111
   ObjectID = "11111"
   SendID = 111111
   SubscriberKey = "aaa@aaa.aaa"
   EventDate = 2016-07-12 00:40:17
   EventType = "aaaa"
   TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID = None
   BatchID = 1
   URLID = 11111
   URL =
```

I have successfully iterated through the items but as a test in my code only pulling back 3 values. ID, PartnerKey, CreatedDate.

I have fed the variables into a Pandas DataFrame and they have successfully populated. My question and problem is that column names are continously repeating at every row level and row numbers on the left hand side are all zero.

**How can I stop the column names from repeating while making the row numbers sequential?**

Code:

```
import ET_Client
import pandas as pd
import json



try:
    debug = False
    stubObj = ET_Client.ET_Client(False, debug)

    ## Modify the date below to reduce the number of results returned from the request
    ## Setting this too far in the past could result in a very large response size
    retrieveDate = '2014-07-11T13:00:00.000'

    #ET call for clicks
    print '>>>ClickEvents'
    getClickEvent = ET_Client.ET_ClickEvent()
    getClickEvent.auth_stub = stubObj   
    getResponse = getClickEvent.get()
    ResponseResults = getResponse.results

    for ClickEvent in ResponseResults:
        ID = str(ClickEvent['ID'])
        PartnerKey = ClickEvent['PartnerKey']
        CreatedDate = ClickEvent['CreatedDate']





        df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[ID],'PartnerKey':[PartnerKey], 'ClickEvent' :[CreatedDate]})

        print df
```

Output now:

```
 ClickEvent          ID            PartnerKey
0 2016-05-21 10:41:46  111111111       None
           ClickEvent          ID PartnerKey
0 2016-05-21 11:29:25  111111111       None
           ClickEvent          ID PartnerKey
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating (and printing) one dataframe for each item in `ResponseResults` instead of a single dataframe with all the results. Try something like this:

```
ids = []
partner_keys = []
created_dates = []
for ClickEvent in ResponseResults:
    ids.append(str(ClickEvent['ID']))
    partner_keys.append(ClickEvent['PartnerKey'])
    created_dates.append(ClickEvent['CreatedDate'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ids, 'PartnerKey': partner_keys,
                   'ClickEvent' : created_dates})
print df
```